# Using shutil library to copy contents of a directory from src to dst, but not the directory itself

Tags: python, directory, shutil, copytree

So I have a directory called /src, which has several contents:

*a.png, file.text, /sub_dir1, /sub_dir2*

I want to copy these contents into destination directory /dst such that the inside of /dst looks like this (assuming /dst is previously empty):

*a.png, file.text, /sub_dir1, /sub_dir2*

I have tried shutil.copytree(src, dst), but when I open up /dst I see:

*/src*

which, although contains everything I want, should not be there, as **I do not want the /src directory itself copied over, only its inner contents**. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake with the file pathways I inputted into the copytree function. The function works as expected, in the way I mentioned I wanted it to in my question.